# Filter R code, for better results for branches

Tags: r

I wrote a code, but now I just want to filter out the onvoldoendes ones. But long time no R studio done so my question is to look only at the shortcomings, how do I filter this out?

```
df %>%
   group_by(Branche, Contract, Algemene_indruk) %>%
   summarise(n = n()) %>%
   pivot_wider(names_from = Algemene_indruk, values_from = n, 
         values_fill = list(n = 0))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use select(-column )

```
df %>%
   group_by(Branche, Contract, Algemene_indruk) %>%
   summarise(n = n()) %>%
   pivot_wider(names_from = Algemene_indruk, values_from = n, 
         values_fill = list(n = 0)) %>%
select(-onvoldoende)
```

To keep the column and just drop the 0s

```
df %>%
   group_by(Branche, Contract, Algemene_indruk) %>%
   summarise(n = n()) %>%
   pivot_wider(names_from = Algemene_indruk, values_from = n, 
         values_fill = list(n = 0)) %>%
filter(onvoldoende != 0)
```

Comment: thank you, and how do i delete the 0's in this section? so i only get onvoldoende with values

Comment: I updated my answer to tell you how to filter out the 0s